# Read content of txt files into lists to find duplicates

Tags: python, readlines

I'm new to Python.

My code should read 2 different .txt files into lists and compare them to find and delete duplicates.

#### Code

```
import os
dir = os.listdir
T = "Albums"
if T not in dir():
    os.mkdir("Albums")
with open('list.txt','w+') as f:
    linesA = f.readlines()
    print(linesA)   # output empty
with open('completed.txt','w+') as t:
    linesB = t.readlines()
    print(linesB)  # output empty
for i in linesA[:]:
    if i in linesB:
        linesA.remove(i)
print(linesA)
print(linesB)
```

I tried the code above with following inputs:

- in `list.txt` I wrote (on separate lines) A, B and C.
- in `completed.txt` I wrote (also on separate lines) A and B.

It should have first output the content of the lists, which were empty for some reasons.

Why are the read lists empty?

Comment: You are opening the files in append mode (`w+`). Try opening them in read mode instead: `with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help:

- I suggest using `not os.path.exists(entry)` instead of `not entry in os.listdir()`, it's not relevant for the problem, but I point it out anyway. *(Also, you overwrote the built-in dir function)*
- I've split up the file using `split("\n")`
- I've changed the way the files are opened to `r+`, this doesn't clear the file unlike `w+`.

*Please note that if you want to use readlines you have to remove the new line for each entry.*

```py
import os

with open('list.txt','w+') as file:
    file.write("Foo\n")
    file.write("Bar")
with open('completed.txt','w+') as file:
    file.write("Bar\n")
    file.write("Python")

T = "Albums"
if not os.path.exists(T):
    os.mkdir("Albums")
with open('list.txt','r+') as f:
    linesA = f.read().split("\n")
    print(linesA)
with open('completed.txt','r+') as t:
    linesB = t.read().split("\n")
    print(linesB)
for entry in list(linesA):
    if entry in linesB:
        linesA.remove(entry)
print(linesA)
print(linesB)
```

Output:

```
['Foo', 'Bar']
['Bar', 'Python']
['Foo']
['Bar', 'Python']
```

Comment: Maybe the assignment `dir = os.listdir` has overwritten the built-in [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#dir) function.

Comment: Yeah, you're right I made a typo.

Answer (score 1):

This makes little sense.

```
dir = os.listdir
```

You wanted to call `os.listdir()`.
What you did was assign a *reference* to that function,
without actually calling the function.

Better to dispense with dir and just phrase it this way:

```
if T not in os.listdir():
```

---

```
with open('list.txt','w+') as f:
    linesA = f.readlines()
    ...
with open('completed.txt','w+') as t:
    linesB = t.readlines()
```

You wanted to open those with `'r'` read mode,
rather than write.

Comment: They do call the listdir function, after assigning it to `dir`: in `if T not in dir()` :)